# Location based windows theme

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

Is there any way to change your Windows theme depending on what network you join?

When i am connected to my home network, I would like to have all of my wallpapers on the slideshow (Windows 7) and my colorful Areo theme.

However, when at school/work or when not connected, I would like the theme to be more plain.

Is there any app or script that can do this?

Comment: What screen saver are you using? I did something very much like this (for the screen saver only) where I wrote a script (batch file) that checked the IP number and, based on that, updated the configuration file for my screen saver (Google Picasa) to display the images that were appropriate for my location. I didn't mess with the theme, however. Windows 7 generates an event when a new IP number is assigned and I used the Task Scheduler to link my script to that particular event. (I also attach network drives appropriate to my location.) Does this sound like what you're after?

Comment: This sounds almost perfect, i do not use any screen saver but if that script could be edited to change themes that would be exactly what i need.

Comment: @BillP3rd You should put that in as an answer.  Crazybmanp: Are you expecting someone to write the script for you?   What have you tried already?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I was actually hoping for some program that does this (i know there are some available for mobile platforms that just detect the network name, so i assumed it wouldn't be too difficult).